# How do I expand a VMware Thick Provisioned Eager Zeroed drive?

Tags: vmware-esx, drive, expansion, thin-provisioning, thick-provisioning

I have a drive that is VMWare Thick Provisioned with a format of Thick Provisioned Eager Zero.

I need to expand this drive by 10Gb, but unlike Thick Provisioned Lazy zero, I can't expand that drive while the machine is on, and unsure of what needs to be done while the machine is off.

How do I expand a drive of this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a blog post on how to do that.

[Extending an EagerZeroedThick Disk](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/06/extending-an-eagerzeroedthick-disk.html)

In summary to extend while keeping in eager zeroed mode, use CLI. to extend it so that it reaches 90 Gigabytes afterwards, do the following:

```
# vmkfstools -X 90G -d eagerzeroedthick  /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/GUEST-001/DISK_1.vmdk                                              


Grow: 100% done. All data on '/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/GUEST-001/DISK_1.vmdk' will be overwritten with zeros from sector <7891200> onwards.
Zeroing: 100% done.
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.